# If $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}-\dots-\frac{1}{11}=17\cdot\left(\frac{17}{A}+\frac{18}{B}+\frac{19}{C} \right)$, find $A, B, C\in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

If $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}\dots-\frac{1}{11}=17\cdot\left(\frac{17}{a}+\frac{18}{b}+\frac{19}{c} \right)$, find $a, b, c\in\mathbb{Z}$

**My attempt:**

The LHS is the alternating sum, it equals $\frac{7303}{27720}$, and $17\nmid7303$, if I multiply $abc$ on both sides,

$$7303\cdot abc=17\cdot 27720 (17bc+18ac+19ab)$$

Since $17\nmid7303$, it means $17|a$ or $17|b$ or $17|c$, and I stuck here? How should I proceed next? Could you give me some hint? Thank you!

Comment: Where did you come across this problem?

Comment: I got this problem from my friend, and this should be a middle school problem, but seems not easy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that easy way to find some solutions for the equation (for mid-school-student, as it is specified in comments) is to group numbers $\frac12$, $-\frac13$, $\frac14$, $-\frac15$, $\frac16$, $-\frac17$, $\frac18$, $-\frac19$, $\frac1{10}$, $-\frac1{11}$ into 3 subsets, so that:

- the sum of numbers of the first subset has numerator $17\times17$ (or its divisors: $1$ or $17$),
- ... of the second subset - $17\times18$ (or any of its divisors: $1$, $2$, $3$, $6$, $9$, $17$, $34$ etc),
- ... of the third subset - $17\times19$ (or its divisors: $1$, $17$, $19$).

One of possible examples:

$$
\frac12-\frac13-\frac15+\frac16-\frac17 = -\frac1{105}, \\
\frac1{10}-\frac1{11} = \frac1{110}, \\
\frac14+\frac18-\frac19 = \frac{19}{72},\tag{1}
$$

another example:
$$
\frac12-\frac13-\frac15+\frac16-\frac17+\frac1{10}-\frac1{11} = -\frac1{2310}, \\
\frac14 = \frac14, \\
\frac18-\frac19 = \frac1{72},\tag{2}
$$

now, multiplying some numerators and denominators from RHS by $17$, $18$ (or its divisors), $19$, it is easy to find some solutions of given equation.

Offtop: actually, I love $(2)$ because it provides solution of more concise equation
$$
 \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}\dots-\frac{1}{11}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} 
$$

Comment: Thank you, so does this mean the solution is not unique?

Comment: @Zion: yes, sure: $$17(-17/30345+18/33660+19/1224),$$
$$17(17/31790-18/32130+19/1224),$$
$$17(17/1156+18/22032-19/746130),$$
etc.

Small solutions (found by exhaustive check):
$$17(17/330-18/272+19/630),$$
$$17(-17/360+18/385+19/1190),$$
$$17(-17/840+18/595+19/3465),$$
etc.